# Step through code in minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, rspec, minitest, byebug

I am wondering is there anyway to step through code in minitest? if I put byebug or debugger in my code and run the test that hits it, the tests run right through and dont stop. Is there anyway to stop the code and step through the way you do in development?

Answer (score 3):

Remember to put in the test group in your Gemfile

```
group :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  . . .
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [minitest-debugger](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest-debugger) or [minitest-byebug](https://github.com/kaspth/minitest-byebug).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pry` gem and put in a binding.pry in your test case if necessary when running minitest.